# Printing 0 in the place of blank space while using %5d in C

Tags: c, printf

In `C`,

```
printf("%5d", 42);
```

Will print 42 using 5 spaces. I want to replace those blank spaces with `0` or any number or character. What should I do ?

Comment: Just do `printf("%05d", 42);`.

Comment: You can look up stuff like this for yourself in any [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for `printf`.

Comment: Not sure if that's a dupe because of _or any number or character_.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar - Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for.